# How to integrate starcounter with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, starcounter

I'm trying to integrate starcounter with visual studio 2013 by installing starcounter but this is not happening, how do I integrate with visual, after integrating how to create a simple project with starcounter.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starcounter 2.3 and newer does not support Visual Studio 2013 anymore, as presented on the https://starcounter.io/download/ page ("System Requirements"). Currently VS 2015 and 2017 are supported.

Comment: It is possible to use Starcounter with VS 2013, but requires manual steps. It would be great to give answer to this question as there always will be need for running Starcounter with VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that needs to be integrated is creating a project from the template. Building is done by MSBuild, so I don't think VS version affects it.

Try to copy an existing project (e.g. https://github.com/StarcounterApps/KitchenSink) and change it to your liking. You will need to do some manual steps to add new pages:

- Open your csproj file in an editor
- add an entry for json file

```
<ItemGroup>
<TypedJSON Include="RadioPage.json">
    <Generator>MsBuild:Compile</Generator>
</TypedJSON>
</ItemGroup>
```

- add an entry for code-behind

```
<Compile Include="RadioPage.json.cs">
  <DependentUpon>RadioPage.json</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

There may be a way to do this in a less manual way, but I don't know how to add dependent file in VS

Comment: if anyone is up to the task, please fix my formatting. I tried, but I can't get codeblocks to work normally under bullet points

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://docs.starcounter.io/v/RC/guides/working-with-starcounter/working-in-visual-studio/), you can see how the Starcounter templates look and read how to use Starcounter without Visual Studio or the extension.

In short, it's no problem using Starcounter with Visual Studio 2013, although, you will miss out on some of the benefits that the extension come with.